# How can I monitor for processes that take up 80%> of the cpu for more than a minute?

Tags: monitoring, process-management, cpu-usage

Sometimes I encounter a process that should have been killed, but instead has been using 100% of the cpu for a while (more than a minute).

I'd like some way to notify myself if this situation occurs. What are my options, and how can I achieve this?

Would I have to write some daemon that periodically watches the cpu % of each process? Or is there some way to determine 'cumulative' cpu time for a process in some time period (for example 1 minute).

Please disregard "how" I intend to be notified - this is irrelevant.

The alternative is needing a human like myself to stare at `htop` for a while.

Answer (score -1):

System resource tests in `monit` come to mind. This can be configured very individually depending on your use-case:

`Monit - utility for monitoring services on a Unix system`

Keep in mind that it may not be shipped with some enterprise distributions (SLES e.g.).

Comment: This does not really seem like an answer?

Comment: There is no answer to a question that asks for brainstorming.